# gsub Find and replace text between two strings in R

Tags: apply, entity-relationship, gsub, regex-group, regex-greedy

i have to use a gsub function in 1000 rows of a column containing text. In every row i want to remove every word occuring between "said:" & "click to expand..." as they are just copy of previous tweet. I am trying to use `gsub` for accomplishing my task

```
content2<-as.data.frame(gsub(".*said:(.*?)expand.... *", " ", content2$txt,fixed=TRUE),stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
```

But, it is deleting only "said:" and expand. The `content2` is 100 observation of 1 variable data frame and I have to do the task for every row. after wiktor response i tried to see if the line he wrote is working or not. i still can see said: and click to expand.... in row 35 so , the code by wiktor is working only for first row i guess (which anyway don't contain the the lines to be deleted). I tried to use apply unsuccessfully to apply this to every row as follows , b3esides being too slow , it's giving me other error :

```
ops<-apply(content2,1,gsub("(said:).*?(click to expand\\.{3})", "\\1 \\2", content2,fixed=TRUE))
```

Just looked through the duplicate post , it does'nt answer my question, which is : What should i do if i wanna replacing all characters between the pattern let say i wanna replace all strings between"said:" and "click to expand" for all rows of a 100X1 data frame. all rows contains set of strings and output should be dataframe of dimensions 100X1: 
`ops<-gsub("(said:).*?(click to expand\\.{3})", "\\1 \\2", test)`

@WiktorStribiżew thanks it seems to work only issue i also wanna remove "said:" & "click to expand..." I made the following reproducible code you can see "said:" & "click to expand..." are not getting removed.

```
test<-as.data.frame(c("he said: i wanna be a rockstar click to expand....ok great but how you gonna do it", 
                      "rockstar said: so how you gonna do it click to expand.... we are wanna be a big rockstar, hang out in collest bar vip with movie star"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ops<-lapply(test, gsub, pattern = '(said:).*?(click to expand\\.{3})', replacement ="\\1 \\2", perl=TRUE)
ops<-as.data.frame(ops,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The code you wrote will it work on all the columns of content2 dataframe. I forgot to mentioned that content2 is a dataframe 20,000 obs. of 1 variable, and i would like to apply the method to every row of content2. i have tr4ied to use apply unsuccessfully. i will change my priginal question as i don't think it's clear right now. thanks!!

Comment: Then you need `content2[] <- lapply(content2, gsub, pattern = '(said:).*?(click to expand\\.{3})',  replacement ="\\1 \\2")`

Comment: You should not have used `fixed=TRUE`, where did you copy it from? You need a regex, not a plain text replacement, please check the duplicate again. Who is Wilson?

Comment: my bad...wanted to tag you. i have used regex(regular expressions, for pattern matching) ........duplicate works on str_replace_all , will check it once again though. thanks again.

Comment: str_replace_all is not necessary, you get the same with `gsub`. If you need a more stable matching, use  PCRE, `content2[] <- lapply(content2, gsub, pattern = '(said:).*?(click to expand\\.{3})', replacement ="\\1 \\2", perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew gotit, thanks man!!, only issue is "said:" &"click to expand..." are also to be removed. the code is keeping these to words.

Comment: Then why did you use a capturing group in the first place? Just use `content2[] <- lapply(content2, gsub, pattern = '(?s)said:.*?click to expand\\.{3}', replacement =" ", perl=TRUE)`

Comment: worked!!. i am still an amateur. Where did you learn this syntax for lapply...since i was not able to find it for last two days. thanks. Also, do you have any tips for using stemdocument in tm package...i have another query on that which i wrote as another question

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257802/r-text-mining-grouping-similar-meaning-words-during-text-mining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all substrings spanning from `said:` till the leftmost `click to expand...` from all the columns in a dataframe you may use

```
content2[] <- lapply(content2, gsub, pattern = '(?s)said:.*?click to expand\\.{3}', replacement =" ", perl=TRUE)
```

The PCRE regex (note the `perl=TRUE` enables the PCRE engine) matches:

- `(?s)` - enables `.` to match line break chars (it does not by default)
- `said:` - a string (to match it as a whole word add `\b` in front)
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `click to expand\.{3}` -  `click to expand...` substring (`\.{3}` matches a `.` char thrice).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257802/r-text-mining-grouping-similar-meaning-words-during-text-mining                                      Can you give me any leads on this another questions?