# R text mining: grouping similar words using stemDocuments in tm package

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, stemming

I am doing text mining of around 30000 tweets, Now the problem is to make results more reliable i want to convert "synonyms" to similar words for ex. some user use words "girl", some use "girls", some use "gal". similarly "give","gave" means only one thing. same for "come,"came". some user use short-form like "plz","pls" etc.
Also, "stemdocument" from tm package is not working properly. it's is converting dance to danc, table to tabl.....is there any other good package for stemming.
I want to replace all these words by just one similar words, in order to count the correct frequency of this data. So my sentiment analysis would be more reliable.
Following is the reproducible code (i cannot include all 30000X1 dataframe here), edited it after comments by ken:

```
 content<-c("n.n.t.t.t.t.t.t.girl.do.it.to.me.t.t.n.t.t.t.t.t.t.n.n.t.t.t.t.t.t.n.n.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.n.n.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.n.t.n.t.t.n.t.t.t.n.t.t.t.tajinkx.said..n.t.t.t.n.t.t.n.t.n.t.n.t.t.n.t.t.n.t.t.n.t.t.tok.guyz...srry.to.sound.dumb.toilets.i.dnt.drink.while.m.just.searching.for.fun..nso.is.going.to.bar.good.for.me.i.dnt.knw.what.washroom.all.happens.there.inside...so.would.like.if.someone.gals.helps.me.thankuu..n.t.t.n.t.t.t.tClick.to.expand....n.t.nBhai.tu.plz.rehne.de.....n.n.t.n.n.t.t.n.t.t.t.n.t.t.n.n.t.t.n.t.n.n.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t..n.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.n.toilet.is.not .t.t.t.t.t.t.t.n.n.t.t.t.t.t.t.n.n.t.t.t.t.t.t.n.t.n.n.t.t.n.t.t.t.n.t.t.n.n.t.t.n.t.n.n.n.t.n.n.n.t.n.n.t.t.n.t.t.t.n.t.t.n.n.t.t.n.t.n.n.t.t.t.t.t..................................................................................................................................................                                                                                       \n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tajinkx said:\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\tok guyz...srry to sound dumb!i dnt drink while m just searching for fun!\nso is going to bar good for me?i dnt knw what all happens there inside...so would like if someone helps me.thankuu!\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\tClick to expand...\n\t\nBhai,tu plz rehne de....\n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\n\n\n\t\n\n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t is this da bar which u guys r talking about???\nSent from my SM-N900 using Tapatalk\n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\n\t")  


    np<-600;postop<-1200;fr<-"yes"#input from GUI

    #wbpage<-function (np,postop,fr){
    #load("data_mpdb.Rdata")
    #content<-as.data.frame(raw_dat[np:postop,],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    #last<-rbind(tail(content,1),head(content,1));colnames(last)<-#c("stopdate","startdate")
    message("Initializing part-1")
    #---------------------data cleaning-----------------------------------------------------
    #replied post
    content2<-as.data.frame(content$txt,stringsAsFactors = FALSE);colnames(content2)<-c("txt")
        content2 <- as.data.frame(gsub("(said:).*?(click to expand\\.{3})", " ", content$txt),stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
        content2<-as.data.frame(lapply(content$txt, gsub, pattern = '(said:).*?(click to expand\\.{3})', replacement ="\\1 \\2", perl=TRUE),stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
        content2<- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(content2)));colnames(content2)<-c("txt");rownames(content2)<-NULL
    #----------------ken's addition: lemmitization---------------------------
    sp <- spacy_parse(as.character(content2$txt), lemma = TRUE)    
    sp$token <- ifelse(!grepl("^\\-[A-Z]+\\-$", sp$lemma), sp$lemma, sp$token)    
    # define equivalencies for please variants
    dict <- dictionary(list(
      please = c("please", "pls", "plz"),
      girl = c("girl", "gal"),
      toilet=c("toilet","shit","shitty","washroom")
    ))    
    toks <- as.tokens(sp) %>%
      tokens(remove_punct = TRUE)
    toks
    new_stopwords<-c("said","one","click","expand","sent","using","attachment",
                     "tapatalk","will","can","hai","forum","like","just",
                     "get","know","also","now","bro","bhai","back","wat",
                     "ur","naa","nai","sala","email","urself","arnd","sim",
                     "pl","kayko","ho","gmail","sm","ll","g7102","iphone","yeah","time","asked","went","want","look","call","sit",
                     "even","first","place","left","visit","guy","around","started","came","dont","got","took","see","take","see","come")

    toks <- tokens_remove(toks, c(stopwords("en"), new_stopwords))
#--------I have to make toks to be same as content2 so that i can use it in # 
 further corpus buildin---------------------------        

    #the data- punctuation, digits, stopwords, whitespace, and lowercase.
    docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(content2$txt));#mname<-Corpus(VectorSource(content2$name))
    message("Initializing part-1.2")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower));#mname<-tm_map(mname,content_transformer(tolower))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation,preserve_intra_word_contractions=TRUE,preserve_intra_word_dashes=TRUE);#mname <- tm_map(mname, removePunctuation)
    message("Initializing part-1.3")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),new_stopwords))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace);#mname <- tm_map(mname, stripWhitespace)
    message("Initializing part-1.4")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords,new_stopwords)
    #------------------------Text stemming------------------------------------------
        #docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument,language="english")

    #-------------sentiment analysis--------------------------------------------------
    message("Initializing part-2")
    n <- 4
    rnorm(10000, 0,1)
    #incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Finished section 1"))

    docs_df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(docs),nrow=length(docs), byrow=F),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    docs_df<-docs_df[-c(2)];content2$editedtxt<-docs_df;

    #----------------fr|fr:----------------------------------------------
    if (fr=="yes"){
    frlogic<-grepl("fr\\s|fr:", docs_df$X1);docs_df<-as.data.frame(docs_df[frlogic=="TRUE",],stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
    docs_df[order(nchar(as.character(docs_df)),decreasing = FALSE),]
    }

    colnames(docs_df)<-c("txt")
    d<-get_nrc_sentiment(as.character(docs_df))
    td<-data.frame(t(d))
    td_new <- data.frame(rowSums(td))
    #Transformation and cleaning
    names(td_new)[1] <-"count"
    td_new <- cbind("sentiment"=rownames(td_new), td_new)
    rownames(td_new) <- NULL
    td_new2<-td_new[1:8,]
    sentimentplot<-qplot(sentiment, data=td_new2, weight=count, geom="bar",fill=sentiment)+ggtitle("sentiments")
    sentimentplot
```

right now i am getting the erro Finding a python executable with spaCy installed...
Error in set_spacy_python_option(python_executable, virtualenv, condaenv,  : 
  No python was found on system PATH

Also,

```
I have to make toks to be same as content2 so that i can use it in # 
 further corpus building for furhter analysis.
```

waiting for your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

That code is not reproducible, since we don't have the input `content2`.  But here's an example that you can use.

What you call "converting synonyms" for variants, like "give" and "gave" or "girl" versus "girls" is not just a matter of stemming, it's a matter of lemmatization (for the give-gave for instance).  To lemmatize, you need functionality not present in the **tm** package.

I recommend you try **spacyr** for lemmatization, and **quanteda** for the rest.  Here's how.  We start with some text, and then parse it using `spacy_parse()`.

```r
txt <- c(
  "The girl and the girls gave all they had to give.",
  "Pls say plz, please, gal."
)
new_stopwords <- c(
  "yeah", "time", "asked", "went", "want", "look", "call",
  "sit", "even", "first", "place", "left", "visit", "guy",
  "around", "started", "came", "dont", "got", "took", "see",
  "take", "see", "come"
)


library("spacyr")
sp <- spacy_parse(txt, lemma = TRUE)
## Found 'spacy_condaenv'. spacyr will use this environment
## successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 2.2.3, language model: en_core_web_sm)
## (python options: type = "condaenv", value = "spacy_condaenv")
sp
##    doc_id sentence_id token_id  token  lemma   pos entity
## 1   text1           1        1    The    the   DET       
## 2   text1           1        2   girl   girl  NOUN       
## 3   text1           1        3    and    and CCONJ       
## 4   text1           1        4    the    the   DET       
## 5   text1           1        5  girls   girl  NOUN       
## 6   text1           1        6   gave   give  VERB       
## 7   text1           1        7    all    all   DET       
## 8   text1           1        8   they -PRON-  PRON       
## 9   text1           1        9    had   have   AUX       
## 10  text1           1       10     to     to  PART       
## 11  text1           1       11   give   give  VERB       
## 12  text1           1       12      .      . PUNCT       
## 13  text2           1        1    Pls    pls  INTJ       
## 14  text2           1        2    say    say  VERB       
## 15  text2           1        3    plz    plz  INTJ       
## 16  text2           1        4      ,      , PUNCT       
## 17  text2           1        5 please please  INTJ       
## 18  text2           1        6      ,      , PUNCT       
## 19  text2           1        7    gal    gal PROPN       
## 20  text2           1        8      .      . PUNCT
```

We're going to convert this into **quanteda** tokens, but first let's replace the token with its lemma (unless it's a part of speech identifier, like "-PRON-").

```r
# replace the token with its lemma (unless it's "-PRON-" for instance)
sp$token <- ifelse(!grepl("^\\-[A-Z]+\\-$", sp$lemma), sp$lemma, sp$token)
```

For your slang variations, we need to define equivalencies manually, which we can do using a **quanteda** "dictionary".

```r
library("quanteda", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
## Package version: 2.0.1
## Parallel computing: 2 of 8 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

# define equivalencies for please variants
dict <- dictionary(list(
  please = c("please", "pls", "plz"),
  girl = c("girl", "gal")
))
```

We'll use that in a minute.  First, let's create a tokens object from the spacyr parsed output, and remove punctuation.

```r
toks <- as.tokens(sp) %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE)
toks
## Tokens consisting of 2 documents.
## text1 :
##  [1] "the"  "girl" "and"  "the"  "girl" "give" "all"  "they" "have" "to"  
## [11] "give"
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "pls"    "say"    "plz"    "please" "gal"
```

Removing stopwords is easy, with the `tokens_remove()` function.

```r
# now remove stopwords
toks <- tokens_remove(toks, c(stopwords("en"), new_stopwords))
toks
## Tokens consisting of 2 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "girl" "girl" "give" "give"
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "pls"    "say"    "plz"    "please" "gal"
```

And now to make the variations of "girl" and "please" equivalent, we use `tokens_lookup()`:

```r
toks <- tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary = dict, exclusive = FALSE, capkeys = FALSE)
toks
## Tokens consisting of 2 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "girl" "girl" "give" "give"
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "please" "say"    "please" "please" "girl"
```

For sentiment analysis, you could apply a sentiment dictionary using `tokens_lookup()` again, and create dfm (document-feature matrix) from this.  (Note: "say" is not really a negative word, but I am using it as such for an example here.)

```r
sentdict <- dictionary(list(
    positive = c("nice", "good", "please", "give"),
    negative = c("bad", "say")
))
tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary = sentdict) %>%
    dfm()
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 2 features (25.0% sparse).
##        features
## docs    positive negative
##   text1        2        0
##   text2        3        1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you please add the code where final output of `toks` is in original `txt` form i.e    `"The girl and the girl give all they had to give."`
                                    `"Please say please, please, gal."`

Comment: I used `reprex::reprex()` to produce everything in my answer (but added comments in the middle of it), so you can substitute the text you want if you copy the code out and run it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am not able to run spaCy, something to do with python libraries. Also, i edited my original question to make it more clear. let me know if it makes sense. I want final variable "toks" as a dataframe similar to content2, to be use in further analysis, as my further code is build on that. please see the edited orinigal question